# HikariProxyConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, hikaricp, ojdbc

I am unable to execute a procedure

```
  public void delete(Long id, String name, List<Long> serialNo) throws Exception {

    try {
        SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource)).withSchemaName(SCHEMA_NAME)
                .withCatalogName(CATALOG_NAME).withProcedureName(board_read)
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("id", OracleTypes.NUMBER))
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("serialNo", OracleTypes.ARRAY, SCHEMA_NAME + "." + "NUMARRAY"));
        Long[] pnumbers = serialNo.toArray(new Long[serialNo.size()]);
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("s_id", new BigDecimal(Id))
                .addValue("p_list", new SqlArrayValue<>(pnumbers));
        call.execute(in);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I saw many examples but still having issue. I always get exception below:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

All the other procedures are working good since its not using arrays.

Comment: Did u get any solution ?